# How to lock "Rotation Mode" in Blender 3.0

Tags: animation, rigging

I would like to know how we can lock the rotation mode in Blender. I have attached image for the reference[image]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "lock"? Once you've chosen the mode, the object or bone will keep the same mode

Comment: yes artists are changing the mode which is causing problems in your pipeline .. to prevent that from happening we want it to be locked so no one can fiddle with it easily or mistakenly

Comment: I believe that Blender's UI does not allow the sort of locking you want.